# How to include google analytics in redirect page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics

I have a page that redirects the user to another site. I want to track the users who click that link.

My code:

```
<!--page start-->
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'code', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <?php
        header('Location: http://wikipedia.org');
    ?>
<!--page end-->
```

The above redirects the user but the google analytics code is never executed. I guess this happens because the redirect is instant and the javascript script doesn't have time to be executed. Can someone please explain how to track the users who click the link?

Comment: Yes, php is server side and it is executed before javascript.. you can try to put e javascript redirect after analytics code

Comment: @Simone M: Thanks, but I need to be sure that redirect is always executed (even to those with javascript off), as it's a download link. I don't want users to say your download is broken...

Comment: Doing the redirect client side is not ideal at all. It will have a noticeable lag, and since the server will respond with a 200, search engines won't know about the redirect and it'll be bad for SEO. Doing it client side **just** to track the analytics is a bad reason since you can do it server side via the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Thanks, but I need to be sure that redirect is always executed (even to those with javascript off)"

Remove the php header. add a no script path. Then do as Simone suggested:

```
<head>
<script>
....google analytics....
</script>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://wikipedia.org" />
</noscript>
</head>
<body onload="onWindowLoad()">
<script>
    onWindowLoad = function(){
        window.location.href = "http://wikipedia.org";
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks! One question: is it ok to use the meta redirect only?

Comment: GA is async, you risk leaving before it finishes? Test it though. perhaps you can do what you're thinking.

Comment: It's async but there is an option to make it sync. Maybe I should change `a.async=1;` to `a.async=0;`?

Comment: Yeah needs testing, I am honestly not sure  a meta tag will wait for a script tag to complete. Never run into the situation!

Comment: Let us know results if you have a moment. This is useful for anyone tracking redirects via GA.

Comment: This solution will not work as is. If you absolutely need to do the redirect client side, you should wait until the hit is successfully sent. Use the `hitCallback` parameter.https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback