# How to make a redirect in PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect, http-headers

**Problem description**

Based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313353/custom-url-redirect-in-wp) answer I have made a PHP custom page for WordPress. The page do the follow: when I go to `www.mysite.com/wp/GoTo/?URL=http://www.google.com`, the browser redirect to `www.google.com`.

The problem is that I would like to use Google Analytics to register the access to the page, in particular when user access a link like the following `www.mysite.com/wp/GoTo/?URL=http://www.google.com&utm_campaign=MyChampaign`.

In other words I have my PHP redirect page

```
<?php


    /*
    Template Name: GoToPage
    */

    /**
     *
     * @package MyTheme
     */

    $url = $_GET["URL"];

    // Remove all illegal characters from a url
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        header("location: " . $url);
        exit;
    } else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
    }
    ?>
```

And I have to insert the Google Analytics snippet.

**1st attempt**

This doesn't work. I think that the problem is that, for the redirect, I have to output ONLY the header and nothing else.

```
<?php


/*
Template Name: GoToPage
*/

/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package MyTheme
 */

$url = $_GET["URL"];

// Remove all illegal characters from a url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-11111111-0', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    header("location: " . $url);
    exit;
} else {
echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

**2ns attempt**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage/506004#506004) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633868/how-to-include-google-analytics-in-redirect-page/28634140#28634140) answers I have tried to convert the client side code from HTML to JavaScript code. This gives me a 404 error for every attemp I have made.

```
<?php


/*
Template Name: GoToPage
*/

/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package MyTheme
 */

$url = $_GET["URL"];

// Remove all illegal characters from a url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo """
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
            ga('create', 'UA-11111111-0', 'auto');
            // Plugins

            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="onWindowLoad()">
        <script>
            window.location.replace(".$url.");
        </script>
        <p>If the page does not automatically redirect please click on<a href=".$url.">this link</a>.</p>
        </body>
    """;
    exit;
} else {
echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

Any idea about how to include the GA snippet in my PHP redirect custom page?

Comment: Your analytics needs to go in the page you redirect to. You can't send output with a location redirect and headers definitely have to be before any content gets echo'd

Comment: @charlietfl I use this to redirect to external page. I can't include any code there. For example if I redirect to Yahoo.it I can't include any code in Yahoo home page.

Comment: Why can't you track this in whatever page user was on to send current GET with the goTo url? Can send message to GA when user submits form or clicks on link

Comment: This would be a good workaround but: 1.I don't know exactly how to made it...can you ref to some tutorial or tell me what to search on Google? 2. most of the link are send via e-mail, would it work if the link are clicked from MS Outlook, Gmail App, browser, ...?